# MySql NULL values from csv seen as string

Tags: mysql, csv, import

my problem is i have a unique constraint on more columns and when i import the csv file, it transforms the NULL in 'NULL'  and sees it as string (same with \N)
any ideas? except disabling and enabling the constraint?

Comment: What does your CSV file look like? MySQL's `\N` is non-standard.

Comment: the first row is : 1 , "CATALEX COM SRL" , 18940204 , J40/13238/2006 , 1 , 9 , 13750 , "STR. PROF. NICOLAE IONESCU, Nr. 7, Et. MANS." , NULL , NULL , 12 , "11 847 950" , "483 050" , "1 200" , 0 , NULL  (spaces between comas added by me now, so it can be read easier, originally there are no spaces between words)

Comment: It's best to edit your question to introduce data like that, the formatting is easier to understand. In that file you have literal text "NULL" in the column, there's no way around that but to rewrite those in advance to `\N` or do it as a second pass as you suggest. Hopefully that's never a value you need to capture literally, [for example as someone's last name](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/).

Comment: i already said, with \N is the same, it just transforms it to a string and makes it '\N'

Comment: How are you loading this data in? That matters.

Comment: workbench, via the import wizzard

Comment: That might not be engaging the correct command. Null values are a big hassle. If you can boil these down to empty strings at the source that would help.